# Get SIP user available status through low-level message

Tags: python, sip, voip, low-level

I'm trying to check if a certain SIP contact is online out of a python application. I already found and tested [sipping](https://github.com/snom-it/SIPPing) as a means for sending SIP messages with python. Now I need to understand which message to send.

Unfortunately so far I only found a [pjsip](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP/Presence) example using their high level code and the buddy/subscribe functions.

So does the SIP protocol provide a simple way to ask a registrar (e.g. linphone.org) "Is user XYZ online?"? What would such a message look like?

Answer (score 0):

The SIP standard provides [OPTIONS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-11) requests which allow querying of "basic state".

> The response to an OPTIONS is constructed using the standard rules
> for a SIP response as discussed in Section 8.2.6.  The response code
> chosen MUST be the same that would have been chosen had the request
> been an INVITE.  That is, a 200 (OK) would be returned if the UAS is
> ready to accept a call, a 486 (Busy Here) would be returned if the
> UAS is busy, etc.  This allows an OPTIONS request to be used to
> determine the basic state of a UAS, which can be an indication of
> whether the UAS will accept an INVITE request.

The only problem is most SIP servers don't implement OPTIONS request handling like that. Instead OTIONS requests are normally treated more like ping requests and SIP servers will respond with 200 OK to indicate they are alive. You could certainly give it a try with the server you are working with but if you always get a 200 OK response that's why.

Apart from OPTIONS requests the response to a successful REGISTER request will hold a list of available contacts for a particular SIP address. That would theoretically allow you to check whether a device was at least connected for that address but it wouldn't tell you anything about the device's status, whether it was on a call, do not disturb etc. Plus REGISTER requests have to be authorised an the list of contacts in the response can contain the IP address of the SIP device which is sensitive information.

Another way would be subscribing to presence event notifications as per the [SIP Presence Event Package](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3856). That is also likely to require the SUBSCRIBE request to be authorised and is not universally supported by SIP servers or providers.

As a last resort you could send an INVITE request but that has the big disadvantage that it could cause the phone at the other end to ring or display a missed call and is also likely to end up in their call history.

Comment: Thanks, OPTIONS request and parse for "200 OK" works fine with linphone registrar.

Comment: You'll need to check if the response is something different when the SIP address is busy on unavailable. I suspect you'll find you always get a 200 OK response n matter what the state.

Comment: Thought it was solved, but unfortunately every client behaves differently. Linphone on linux accessed through local network sends "200 OK" while Linphone on linux online sends "200 Ok". Linphone on iPhone does not respond to calls. Neither does Linphone on Windows. Would be great to see what a "default" OPTIONS call has to look like.